# aurelia property observer not being disposed

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

Folks,

I have a ViewModel which gets a singleton injected into its constructor.
In the constructor I then create an observer on a property in the singleton instance.

In the detached() function I dispose the observer subscription.

```
constructor( singleton: MySingleton, bindingEngine: BindingEngine )
{
    this.observer = bindingEngine
        .propertyObserver( singleton, 'state' )
        .subscribe( ( newValue, oldValue ) => this.onStateChanged( newValue, oldValue ) ) ;

}

// Sample updated with offending code    
detatched()
{
    // was calling it incorrectly like this - thought TypeScript would have flagged the problem
    // this.observer.dispose ;

    // and it should have been like this
    this.observer.dispose() ;
    // and setting observer to undefined is probably the safest
    this.observer = undefined ;
}
```

What is happening is that everytime I navigate to the page a new instance of the ViewModel is created, and when I leave the page the detatched is called. (which I expect would happen).

However the observer is not getting deleted/disposed and the instance of the ViewModel stays in memory. When the 'state' value changes and onStateChanged is fired it does so for all the number of page instances that have been created. ie the number of times I have navigated to/away from the page.

This is all very obvious with debug statements being logged.

Should observer.dispose() not be removing the observer?
Should my ViewModel instance not be disposed also?

Thanks

Donal

Comment: is your question about TypeScript or JavaScript? please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: question was about Aurelia observer disposal - independent of typescript of javascript... @naXa

Answer (score 1):

Observer should just be disposed in your code, as you can see from this example https://codesandbox.io/s/ovvp7m05o5

- On landing, clicking anywhere in the document will increase counter + log `Click changed called`
- When navigating to page 2, clicking anywhere will increase counter + not log `Click changed called`

I think you accidentally override the observer reference in your class. The observer that was created once in constructor could never be referenced again to dispose properly.

Comment: apologies for this but I was stupidly calling dispose without the brackets... eg this.observer.dispose; It is working now...

Comment: Please help update your Question with some details so future reader will not be confused. @DonalMcWeeney